# Run All Thread groups for every 1 hour once

Tags: jmeter

1.In My Test plan I have 5 Scripts(5 Thread groups)
2.For every 1 hour once i want to trigger this script.(All the thread groups should run once)
3.Once the first run is completed it should wait one hour time again the script should run..

Can Any Help me please how to do this scenario

Answer (score 1):

1. The easiest way is using your operating system scheduling mechanism, i.e. :

   - [Windows Task Scheduler](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc748993(v=ws.11).aspx)
   - [Linux Crontab](http://kvz.io/blog/2007/07/29/schedule-tasks-on-linux-using-crontab/)
   - [MacOSX launchd](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/ScheduledJobs.html)
2. Alternative way would be running JMeter via continuous integration server like [Jenkins](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/continuous-integration-101-how-run-jmeter-jenkins), this way you will get scheduling, parameterization, build history and performance trend charts via [Performance Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Performance+Plugin)
3. One more option would be running a JMeter test non-stop, i.e. set Thread Groups to run Forever. You can create a 1-hour delay between iterations by adding [Test Action](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Action) sampler configured to pause threads for `3600000` milliseconds. Optionally you can add [Synchronizing Timer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Synchronizing_Timer) to act as a "rendezvous point" so Test Action sampler would be executed by all threads simultaneously.